# Copy a specific column in a different sheet and when you run the macro it moves columns to the right

Tags: vba, loops, copy, paste

i need some help as i am experienceing a problem, pretty new to VBA. i want to copy that data from L5-L18, excluding some cells and paste it to column B of sheet(In) and create a button that every time i push it to copy the data from column B ,sheet(Data) to the sheet(in) and move columnto the right. like first time column b, next time column c...every time i push the button.. much appreciated

```
Sub Macro2()
 Sheets("Data").Select

 Range("L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L13,L14,L15,L16,L17,L18").Select

 Range("L18").Activate

Selection.Copy

 Sheets("In").Select

 Range("B5").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

 Range("B5").Offset(0, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method A**

To insert into column B and shift everything else to the right try this:

```
Sub offsetCol()
    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Set wksData = Sheets("Data")

    Dim wksIn As Worksheet
    Set wksIn = Sheets("In")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    wksIn.Range("B5:B10").Value = wksData.Range("L5:L10").Value
    wksIn.Range("B11:B16").Value = wksData.Range("L13:L18").Value
End Sub
```

---

**Method B**

Find last column in sheet and tack on information to next available:

```
Sub offsetCol()
    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Set wksData = Sheets("Data")

    Dim wksIn As Worksheet
    Set wksIn = Sheets("In")

    Set rLastCell = wksIn.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wksIn.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    wksIn.Range(Cells(5, rLastCell.Column + 1), Cells(10, rLastCell.Column + 1)).Value = wksData.Range("L5:L10").Value
    wksIn.Range(Cells(11, rLastCell.Column + 1), Cells(16, rLastCell.Column + 1)).Value = wksData.Range("L13:L18").Value
End Sub
```

---

**Method C**

Find last column in row 5 and tack on info in next available column:

```
Sub offsetCol()
    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Set wksData = Sheets("Data")

    Dim wksIn As Worksheet
    Set wksIn = Sheets("In")

    Dim rLastCol As Integer
    rLastCol = wksIn.Cells(5, wksIn.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    wksIn.Range(Cells(5, rLastCol), Cells(10, rLastCol)).Value = wksData.Range("L5:L10").Value
    wksIn.Range(Cells(11, rLastCol), Cells(16, rLastCol)).Value = wksData.Range("L13:L18").Value
End Sub
```

Starting Data:

[image]

---

Results (Method C):

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for you answer... works perfectly but i would like the original column to be steady and the new column to be shifted to the right.. basically it is going to work as data for each month.. so the original first column is Jan.... much appreciated... do you know what i should amend??

Comment: See edit, I added a method at the bottom to use the last available column.  Is this what your looking for?

Comment: i looks ok but is not running for some reason.. when i try to run it it doesn't do anything.. at yours is it running??

Comment: If your sheet has a lot of data it will find the last column of any row.  Try this at the end of your code: `MsgBox (rLastCell.Column)` this will tell you the column number that the data is going into.

Comment: well it works, but i can't understant why it starts from the 25th columns and not from b and them move on to the right.. the first aproach was slightly off ... imagine that in B goes Jan,c->Feb,d->mar and does to the right.. can we do that you think???? thank you for your time honestly..

Comment: Okay, see last edit.  I think I understand what you want a little better now.  Try Method C.

Comment: perfect!!!! thank you very much... i have to do some criteria but this exactly what i wanted... much appreciated it. btw do you know any good book fir basics in vba?? maybe something i can find it in pdf???

Comment: Glad to help, please mark as accepted.  I don't have a book recommendation but you can learn a lot just by regularly coming here and seeing peoples questions get answered by a variety of solutions.  Also, using the macro recorder is an excellent way to see what goes on behind the scenes and getting your feet wet to what is available.

Comment: hi thanks for the feedback..as a last question is this possible to be expanded?? i mean in Data sheet i have B5:B10-B13:B18 and L5:L10-L13:L18, so now i have two columns but same process. so i want to copu those ranges and put it in input sheet in columns next to each other.so now each time i want it to move by one to the right, but instead for the last columns copy two or more. say i have Jan-Feb and copy it. next time i will have Feb-Mar so i want it to move it as a whole thing.. is my question clear??? thanks in advance..

Comment: to make it more clear, in "data: i have columns B,D,F , and want them to copy to Input in columns B,C,D. next time i press the but i want it to copy from Data B and copy to Input C, Data D copy to Input D and generate a new column for Data F. so it overwrites the whole data on column to the right each time...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the question - copy from **location A** to **location B**, is not very clear, but I am guessing this is what you need.  Put this under a macro of a button:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim rng As Range
Sheets("IN").Range("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheets("Data").Select
Set rng = Range("L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L13,L14,L15,L16,L17,L18")
rng.Copy Sheets("IN").Range("B:B")

End Sub
```

Comment: Oops didn't see @portland runner has an answer already.  Go with his if it works fine for you

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want the first time i press the button  the data to be copied in column b, the next time the new data to be printed in c.. so the b remains constant, like exporting data for different months, so i want Jan->Feb->Mar.. dont what Jan to be moving.. what do you think?? regards my friend.

Comment: Think Portland have the answer for your already, I will not bother updating mine.  By the way, eyeshield 21 is a good amine =)

Comment: yep couldnt find a bettet nickname, but one piece is my favourite.. by far the best one!! thank you for your time..